# relative logo in vertical middle of 100% height div

Tags: html, css

The fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8wEYx/2/ illustrates my problem. I have a header div that is 94% of the screen and a navbar that takes up the other 6% at the bottom. Now my problem is that I'd like my logo to be in the vertical middle of the header div but without any fixed padding. Any suggestions please?

**HTML :**

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="logo">
                    <p class="silence">silence<span>.</span></p>
                    <p class="tagline">Business solutions to the point</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 @import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
    html, body {
        height:94%;
    }
    #header {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #logo {
        margin-top:250px;
    }
    #logo p.silence {
        font-size:8em;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #logo span {
        color:#c00;
    }
    #logo p.tagline {
        margin-top:25px;
        text-align:center;
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    #navbar ul {
        margin:auto;
        padding:30px 0;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }
    #navbar ul li {
        display:inline-block;
        list-style:none;
        margin:0 25px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Answer (score 0):

```
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    margin-top:-62px;
    top:50%;
}
```